# AWK merge two different sequential file set in a loop

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I have two sets of files such as P_1.dat, P_2.dat, P_3.dat,...P_45.dat and S_1.dat, S_2.dat, S_3.dat,....,S_45.dat. What I'm trying to do is merge each pair (P and S) sequentially in a loop and assign a new name to the result file.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=45;++i) paste P_i.dat S_i.dat}' > NEWNAME_i.dat
```

Comment: Please show us a small sample of your input files and the desired output. At the moment, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: So they're the filenames - what do they have in them? Show us a small sample with a few input files, including the contents. Then show us what the result would be for that example.

Comment: Why do you need awk for that? Bash script `for i in {1..45} ;do paste P_${i}.dat S_${i}.dat > NEWNAME_${i}.dat;done` is enough right?

Comment: Each of them contain one record. Instead of using paste command to merge them such as "paste P1.dat  S1.dat > L1.dat" and goes on till "paste P45.dat S45.dat > L45.dat" I'm looking for an awk loop that will help me merge all pairs with one execute. Such as awk' {for(i=1;i<=45;++i) paste P(i).dat S(i).dat > L(i).dat}' .As a result I will get L1,L2,L3,...L45.

Comment: thanks 7171u. That's what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need a shell loop:

```
for i in {1..45}; do
    paste "P_$i.dat" "S_$i.dat" > "L_$i.dat"
done
```

The resulting series of files will each contain the content from the two corresponding P and S files.

If your shell doesn't understand brace expansion, then you can achieve the same thing using a `while` loop:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 45 ]; do
    paste "P_$i.dat" "S_$i.dat" > "L_$i.dat"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Clearly in this case, 45 can be replaced with a variable.

Alternatively if your shell supports it, you can use a C-style `for` loop:

```
max=20
for (( i = 1; i < max; ++i )); do
    paste "P_$i.dat" "S_$i.dat" > "L_$i.dat"
done
```

...or you could just loop through the files themselves:

```
for file in P_*.dat; do
    i=${file%.dat}
    i=${number#P_}
    paste "P_$i.dat" "S_$i.dat" > "L_$i.dat"
done
```

Comment: thank you. I got one more thing to ask... how can I arrange inside "{1..45}" to be the "{1..number of P(or S)_$i.dat files}. For instance If I got files from P1 to P20.dat I want it to be {1..20}.